# GSON parse error:Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING when response value is null

Tags: java, android, json

I have search for many similar questions  "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING" but nothing work for me.
Here is my json string:

```
{
"result": "true",
"data": [{
    "from": {
        "user_id": "user1",
        "name": "user1",
        "avatar": "http://zzzzzz.jpg"
    },
    "request_id": "user1:user2"
},
{
    "from": "null",
    "request_id": "user1:user3"
}]
}
```

This is my mapping entities:

```
  public class GetFriendResponse {
    public boolean result;
    public List<FriendRequest> data;
  } 

  public class FriendRequest {
     public String request_id;
     public UserInfo from;
  }

  public class UserInfo {
    public String user_id;
    public String name;
    public String avatar;
 }
```

And I parse json like this:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 GetFriendResponse  response = gson.fromJson(jsonString,GetFriendResponse.class);
```

I have check and see the problem is when the result contains `"from": "null"`, it give an error. 
Is there any idea?

Comment: Gson is outdated... Json lib is excellent I find...

Comment: but really you should be using getters and setters and not public variables in your classes!

Comment: Why do you say Gson is outdated?

Comment: I have read that it is incredibly slow compared with more modern libraries.

Comment: I really happy if you have another way worked for me because I can't change the json result from web service. I don't care what library is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the webservice return null or {}, not "null".

Comment: The problem is I don't have permission to change the web service.

Comment: "null" is not JSON standard. [http://www.json.org/] therefore, you are going to have to create a non-standard json parser.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Let me try this way. Thanks!